# Can I use HSA money to pay for family member that isn't covered by an HDHP?

Tags: united-states, hsa, hdhp, health-insurance

If I'm in an HDHP, but my wife is on a different plan (non-HDHP), can I use money from my HSA to pay for her costs until she reaches her deductible?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It appears that this is the case.  From IRS [Publication 969](http://www.irs.gov/publications/p969/ar02.html#en_US_2011_publink1000204081), *Health Savings Accounts and Other Tax-Favored Health Plans*

> Qualified medical expenses are those incurred by the following persons.
>
> You and your spouse.
>
> All dependents you claim on your tax return.
>
> Any person you could have claimed as a dependent on your return except that:
>
> > The person filed a joint return,
> >
> > The person had gross income of $3,700 or more, or
> >
> > You, or your spouse if filing jointly, could be claimed as a dependent on someone else's 2011 return.